# React-native deep linking not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'd like two buttons in my customerServices component to deep link to the phone's dial and the phone's email client. However the Linking.openURL not working on iOS, just on Android. What would you recommend? I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, Linking } from 'react-native';
import Container from '../../components/Container';
import { Images, Colors, FontFamily } from '../../components/Theme';
import InnerContainer from '../../components/InnerContainer';

export default class CustomerService extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={styles.container} type="mancsTRBL">
                <InnerContainer style={styles.innerContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sideCard} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL("tel://+36201234567") }}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Image source={Images.call} style={styles.icon} />
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.serviceHeader}>Customer service</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.serviceText}>+36 20 123 4567</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sideCard} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL("mailto:email@email.com") }}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Image source={Images.email} style={styles.icon} />
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.serviceHeader}>Email </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.serviceText}>email@email.cc</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </InnerContainer>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it on a real device or just in the simulator?

Comment: @Tim just in the simulator. is it possible that they don't work the same way?